# BlueMix SingleSignOn, How to call REST API of a BlueMix App with SSO service enabled

Tags: rest, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I have a BlueMix app with a few RestAPI calls. After adding SignleSignOn Service to this app, i am not able to make RestAPI calls via the app endpoint. Is there a way to pass the Authentication of SSO via the REST call headers ?

The SSO is configured with cloud Directory enabled. How should i pass user details along with Bluemix app Rest api call?

As of now i can only use the browser to login via SSO into the app and perform REST call only in the same browser.

Example RestCall -> http://myapp.mybluemix.net/sm/metadata

web.xml extract:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSc hema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>SolutionManager</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>RequestRedirect</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ibm.ba.ssl.RedirectFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RequestRedirect</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ibm.ba.sm.auth.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>   
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>   
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>sample</display-name>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.ba.ers.ErsServlet</servlet-class>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <async-supported>false</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<resource-ref>
    <description>MQLight Service</description>
    <res-ref-name>jms/MQLight-mc</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<listener>
  <listener-class>
      com.ibm.ba.SMAppStart
  </listener-class>
</listener>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Authenticated Users</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ALL</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Thanks,
Lokesh

Comment: Is the caller of this REST API on Bluemix and bound to the same SSO service?

Comment: Yes, the REST api is part of my bluemix app and Exposed via the App's Endpoint. Without SSO service if i do a GET call for the above Example Restcall, it would return a JSON. After binding the SSO to my App, the same GET call with return a HTML of the SSO landing page. How should i be passing SSO credentials along with the GET call to reach My app's endpoint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access any service on Bluemix, you need to provide bearer token to provide along with it. 
To get bearer token, use the below API call:

**POST** http://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token

**request body:** "grant_type=password&username=[your-bluemix-id]&password=[your-bluemix-password]

**headers:** { 'authorization': 'Basic Y2Y6', 
               'accept': 'application/json', 
               'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded
             }

**Response** would be like:
{
  "access_token": "[value_from_access_token]",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": "[value2]",
  "expires_in": 43199,
  "scope": "password.write cloud_controller.write openid cloud_controller.read",
  "jti": "20e70e6e-5700-476c-bc15-7869c5fb4b07"
}

To make REST calls for you services, use below mentioned headers:

{'accept': 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json',

**'authorization': 'bearer[space][value_from_access_token]**'}

Comment: Thanks for replying devesh, I am not trying to access the SingleSignOn service, i am only trying to reach my own app's endpoint on bluemix via REST. For Example: if my app URL is http://myapp.mybluemix.net/ and i do a GET call, it will return a HTML response. After adding SSO service to my Bluemix app. The same GET call returns the HTML of the SSO page. How should i pass the credentials of Cloud Directory on SSO to get past it and reach my app's endpoint ?

Comment: Okay, then check out these links:
http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-saml2-bearer-17 and
http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-05#page-21

Comment: @devesh-ahuja do you know the endpoint is for IAM as opposed to UAA? Thanks

Comment: @EShindler Sorry, I am not aware of that.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to find out? I'm trying to switch my application from UAA to IAM....

Comment: @EShindler This might help you - https://dev-console-regional.stage1.ng.bluemix.net/docs/developing/Access-Management/clientid.html#client-id-and-secret .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answers you have received so far are not correct for the new SSO service (which includes support for in-cloud registry). When you added the SSO service to your application, J2EE security constraints are applied to your application and the SSO service becomes the authentication source for satisfying those security contraints. This is ultimately why you currently require the browser cookie(s) obtained after browser authentication to make your REST calls.

Without seeing your deployed applications web.xml and server.xml files it's not clear what the best way forward is, however you may need to build an EAR file with explicitly defined security constraints and make your REST API endpoints unauthenticated or authenticated via another mechanism.

Comment: Thanks @Shane Weeden, I have added the web.xml to this post. The server.xml used is auto generated by the liberty server on bluemix, How can i make the REST api not to authenticate via SSO ?

Comment: Hi Shane, can you please give some ideas on how to make REST API endpoints unauthenticated via another mechanism ? I am still Bolcked on this issue not able to get around SSO on bluemix for rest api